# Backbone.history.start with a specific fragment

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, pushstate

I want to start my Backbone router at a specific action sometimes, different than the one that was navigated to. How can I change it so that when I call `Backbone.history.start` it goes to a specific action/fragment other than the one in the URL?

```
Backbone.history.start
  pushState: true
  root: "/"
```

Maybe there's some option, or maybe there's a way for me to change the fragment before making that function call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass "silent" option and than call "navigate":

```
Backbone.history.start({ silent: true });
router.navigate('test', { trigger: true });
```

In this case hash that was before you called Backbone.history.start will be ignored. Hash will be changed to 'test' and the same route function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Backbone.history.navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) will navigate to the route in the first argument, if the second argument is `true`, it will also trigger the route function.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('users/sam', true);
```

Comment: But what I'm talking about is before Backbone.history is initialized. After it's initialized, it automatically routes to the `window.location.hash`. I've tried changing it before calling `Backbone.history.start` but that doesn't do anything.